# C# - Get date difference of Nullable DateTime in int

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two DateTime variables of Nullable types.

```
DateTime? date1 = new DateTime();
DateTime? date2 = new DateTime();
```

I need to get the difference of these two dates in an int variable. What I have tried is -

```
int daysBetweenDate = (date2 - date1).GetValueOrDefault().TotalDays;
```

But I am unable to solve the issue.

> It is taken care that the difference of these two dates will be
>   calculated only if their values aren't null.

Comment: `DateTime ?date1` is quite horrible... You should write `DateTime? date1`, because `DateTime? date1, date2` date2 is `DateTime?`

Comment: `TotalDays` is a double. You have to cast it to `int`, or make `daysBetweenDate` a double. Other than that, i don't see your problem

Comment: @Pikoh That the default of `DateTime` is `DateTime.MinValue`, that is a very far far date :-) If `date2 == DateTime.Today` and `date1 == null`, then `DateTime.Today - DateTime.MinValue` will probably cause an overflow somewhere.

Comment: Oh,now I see @xanatos :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would write something like:

```
int? daysBetweenDate = date1.HasValue && date2.HasValue ? (int?)(date2.Value - date2.Value).TotalDays : null;
```

So `daysBetweenDate` is `null` if at least one of `date1` and `date2` is `null`.

Comment: `GetValueOrDefault` in question does not return `DateTime`. It returns `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @Evk That was indeed the mistake I was making.

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to return null when one (or both) of the dates is null, you can write like this (if you can use `?` operator which is available in C# 6.0 compiler):

```
int? days = (int?) (date1 - date2)?.TotalDays;
```

Comment: This from C# 6.0 :-) The null conditional operator is very beautiful... The only sad thing is that we had to wait 2017 to have it :-)

Comment: @xanatos C# 6.0 is available for about 2 years already I think, and is definetely available in VS 2015, so no need to wait for anything :)